# Unsupported partition key type MESSAGE on kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, grpc

In my company we are using google `grpc` and `kafka` for communication between the different parts of our system.

I need to create some event measages for a new service that will then need to be deployed to the `kafka` cluster.

I’ve defined the events with a partition key of type Message as I define the events in `proto`.

When releasing to the `kafka` cluster I get the error saying that the type Message is unsupported for the partition key field.

Is it that `Kafka` only supports primitive types for partition key or can it also be a complex object?

Tried having the partition key in this fashion:

```
EventKey event_key = 1;
```

And I am using this property in the `kafka.definitions` as

```
partition_key = ‘event_key’
```

Comment: What library are you using here? Kafka doesn't natively offer gRPC connectivity